# searching an unsorted list of elements in python

Tags: python, search

Apart from Binary search - do we have any other algorithm having lesser number of comparisons.
Further Binary search would work on a Sorted list. what if the elements are unsorted ?

if Number of elements (= n) is a big number. Then the run time would be high, if I opt to sort it and then run a binary search on the same.

is there any other alternative.

Comment: Try a benchmarking the speeds of converting to a Set and using a "in" lookup

Comment: If you are searching the list only once, then you can use linear search `O(n)`. But if you are serching the list multiple times then a `O(nlogn)` sort is a one-time overhead & your searches become `O(logn)`. If you are checking for set-membership, try looking at data structures like sets & bloom filters

Answer (score 0):

Sorting has a cost of O(n*log(n)) in the mean case if you use Timsort, Python's default sorting algorithm, so it's only worth ordering if you are gonna perform many searches and the array is not gonna have new elements since you'll have to reorder which has cost O(n).

On the other hand, since you have to look every value individually, I don't think there are better ways unless you use parallel programing, that way several threads could look in different values at the same time.

Comment: Why would you use quicksort in Python?

Comment: Quicksort is theoretically the fastest algorithm which can achieve `O(n*log(n))` in the best case scenario, I don't think it depends on the programming language you use...

Comment: It depends on the language because of the sorting algorithm(s) already included in the language. Python's sorting algorithm is Timsort, so you'd have to implement quicksort yourself. Which is more work, and (unless you implement it in C) going to be much slower than the built-in sort. Plus Timsort has best case O(n) and it's stable. So that's a lot of disadvantages if you use quicksort in Python and I don't see why anyone would do that.

Comment: Okay, you're right, using the default algorithm in python is the fastest way as I could check, kudos for that.
However the mean time is still o(n*logn) so it doesn't affect the overall answer.